# react native video tag eroor

Tags: reactjs, react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - file:/C:/Users/Ritik/.m2/repository/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - file:/E:/react native/Imusic/node_modules/react-native/android/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - file:/E:/react native/Imusic/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - https://www.jitpack.io/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-video

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set
up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - file:/C:/Users/Ritik/.m2/repository/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - file:/E:/react native/Imusic/node_modules/react-native/android/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - file:/E:/react native/Imusic/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - https://www.jitpack.io/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-video

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s

```
at makeError (E:\react native\Imusic\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at E:\react native\Imusic\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (E:\react native\Imusic\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:106:5)
at async Command.handleAction (E:\react native\Imusic\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **build.gradle** in your **Android folder** you need to change allprojects (not in build dependencies) like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, Clean cache and build again.